# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'times' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'times' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sa_schedule` (`cinema_id`, `movie_id`, `times`) values (-, [], ))

this is my form

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Cinema Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="cinemaname">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Movie Title</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="movietitle">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Time Schedule</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="timesched">
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function addcinema(Request $request)
{  //some codes here

    $addcine = new Schedule();
    $addcine->times = $request->timesched;
   //some codes here
    $addcine->save();

    return view ('dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `times` column nullable. Additionally you may define default value for it. Using migrations, direct db modification or phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2):

The times column has to have a value unless you update the column to allow null.

Comment: but what i am trying to do is create a new entry to enter the database. am i going on the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

```
change your form to look like this <div class="form-group">
  <label>Cinema Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="cinemaname">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Movie Title</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="movietitle">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Time Schedule</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="timesched">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).